# Displaying Eloquent relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to display orders to sellers but also buyers can be able to see their orders. I have created all the necessary relationships and the data is on the database. I'm stuck in trying to query this data from database so i can show it. I have these tables orders table, order_product table. Here is how they look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOZVQ.jpg

I have tried below functions but still no luck in solving the problem.
If you need more information, just comment and i will provide.

Here are my functions

```
// Seller Orders 
 public function viewOrders(User $user)
 {
 // all sells
 $sells = $user->allOrderFromSellers();
 dd($sells);// this returns empty array
 return view('orders')->with(compact('sells'));
 }


 //Buyer Orders
 public function myOrders(User $user)
 { 

  return view('myOrders', compact('user','orders'));
  dd($orders);
 }
```

And here are the models.

```
 order_product.php

 <?php
 namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class OrderProduct extends Model
 {
 protected $table = 'order_product';
 protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'buyer_id',  'seller_id','product_id', 'quantity'];

 public function products()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Products_model');
 }

 public function buyer()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'buyer_id');
 }

 public function seller()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'seller_id');
 }

 public function order()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
 }
 }
```

and this is User.php

```
 <?php
 namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

 class User extends Authenticatable
 {
 use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'Seller'
 ];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token', 
 ];

//public function isSeller() {
 //   return $this->seller;
//}

 public function products()
 {
  return $this->hasMany(Products_model::class);
 }
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
 ];

 public function orders()
 {
   return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class,     Products_model::class, 'buyer_id', 'seller_id', 'product_id');
 }

 public function orderFromBuyers()
 {
  return $this->hasManyThrough(OrderProduct::class,    Products_model::class, 'buyer_id', 'product_id');
 }

 public function orderFromSellers()
 {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(OrderProduct::class, Products_model::class, 'seller_id', 'product_id');
 }

 public function allOrderFromBuyers()
 {
 return $this->hasMany(OrderProduct::class, 'buyer_id');
 }


 public function allOrderFromSellers()
 {
 return $this->hasMany(OrderProduct::class, 'seller_id');
 }

 }
```

the above functions give me this collection as result:

```
"Collection {#281 ▼
    #items: []
}"
```

please help me on this, i have spent so much time but nothing is working.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to call the `->get()` method for actually retrieving the data. So I'd be `$sells = $user->allOrderFromSellers()->get()`. Besides that I don't see anything wrong at first glance

Comment: It's just showing empty array like before@PtrTon

Comment: You could try dumping the actual sql generated by your models and debugging that. Although it seems like the relationship is defined as it should be, the data is in the database and the model gets called correctly so I don't know why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship is not correct
You need to use many to many and has many through relations, as order has many products and product has many orders ....
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through
*Don't create model and relations for pivot table* like OrderProduct 
That is not correct
In this case order_product is a pivot table

So this is a correct Models

For Order model

```
public function products() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'order_product');
}
```

For Product model

```
public function orders() 
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'order_product');
}
```

After that you can handle rest of things

```
$order = Order::with('products')->findOrFail($id);
$products = $order->products
```

Comment: @khachick It say `"Undefined variable: id"`

Comment: Yes, this is a just sample, here you can add order id for test

Comment: $id = 1; Usually you should get this id from route param

Comment: am getting this error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_product.products_model_id'` @Khachik